Can't make Tailscale work on TrueNAS Scale with Nginx Proxy Manager
I'm totally new to all of this and I've been trying to set Tailscale up for a week now, but no luck. Watched a lot of tutorials. Also tried at first Caddy, but had problems with Cloudflare certificates. Currently have Nginx PM running with Let's Encrypt certificate.
If I go to sub.mydomain.tld, I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
If I try to open my-nas-machine.xxx-yyy.ts.net directly, I'm greeted with the TrueNAS UI

I have my domain with a wildcard CNAME (*.mydomain.tld) entry pointing to my-nas-machine.xxx-yyy.ts.net
TrueNAS is set up as an exit node and it advertises subnet routes (192.168.1.0/24)
Running also Tailscale client on Windows 11 with default settings and it's on the Tailscale dashboard
Tried also on Android phone, but still same result
Tried port forwarding on router 80/443 >> 30021/30022 (Nginx PM ports on TrueNAS)

Please add a comment if I need to add more information to this for you to be able to help me. I'm not sure what is needed to figure all this out :/
Using latest versions of all OSes and apps. Tailscale and Nginx PM on TrueNAS Scale installed via official catalog
Thanks
